Is it normal Spring Boot Migrator take long to run?
I am upgrading an legacy Spring aplication to Spring Boot 3.X.
I hava already included Spring Boot 2.7.14 and updated everything to this version.
The application is running smoothly with Spring Boot 2.7.14.
I am trying to upgrade it to Spring Boot 3 using Spring Boot Migrator (https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-boot-migrator).
It is running for almost a week. Is it normal? How long it is supose to take?
